# pentaho migration EE to CE

Tags: import, migration, export, pentaho

I want to export the entire repository of Pentaho EE to Pentaho CE. It gives me errors. Can I migrate from Enterprise to community? Or can I just from `CCE` to `EE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, provided none of the components are using a licensed products (Analyzer, Interactive Reports).

Install a fresh CE version and copy/paste the pentaho-solution directory. It should work, but you will see the components using licensed product but nothing will happen if you click on it.

Warn not to copy the .pentaho hidden sub-directory of the home, and not touch the pentaho/biserver/licenses.

Comment: Thanks, when I take a little time I try it